# Automatically mark the order status to complete - Digital Download product

Tags: magento2

I am using Magento 2.0.4 and finding a way to automatically mark the order status to 'Complete' once the payment is complete.

At the moment what is happening is once the payment is complete the order status is marked as 'Processing' and once the admin opens the order and provide some comments and submit the order becomes 'Complete'

I do not want admin to do this manually.  How can I complete the order as soon as the customer complete their payment.

Answer (score 3):

As in magento2 there is no functionality to change order status to complete when customer made the payment,but it can be done through observer.We have to use the event `sales_order_place_after` in `events.xml` file.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="order_change_status" instance="Namesapce\Modulname\Model\File" shared="false" />
    </event>
</config>
```

In `File.php` use below code

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$order_status = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($order->getId());
$order_status->setStatus('complete');
$order_status->save();
```

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like your solution requires to edit the Magento core files which I don't want to do that.  Can this code put on a separate module?

Comment: yes you have to put this code in your separate module..as changing core files may create problem at the time of placing order