# Magento 2 - Setting orders to "complete" automatically after placing an order?

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, magento2.4

I'm trying to set the order status of new orders to "complete" after a new order has been placed but can't see how this is done in the Magento backend.

I can't select the "complete" status as default for any payment methods I'm using.

Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: This might help - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109205/automatically-mark-the-order-status-to-complete-digital-download-product/109265

Comment: Hey, do you want to set the order to complete right after it's placed or when the payment it's completed? If is right after it's placed it the above comment link but all payment methods should have the option to set the order as complete when it's payment it's confirmed. If you set it to complete as soon as it's placed you'll have to check if the payment was really done manually.

Comment: Hey, as it's a B2B shop it only offers invoice as payment method. So I'd like to set all orders to Complete after they've been placed.